# Is using "android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" twice in the manifest page redundant?

Tags: android, permissions, flashlight

I am new to XML and android app development in general. I cloned the code for an app from github, for learning purposes.

In the manifest page, this line is used twice `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />`

Should I remove it because it is redundant, or is it used twice specifically for some reason that I should be aware of?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's redundant.  You only need to request a permission once, requesting it a second time does nothing.